# Fantasy novel series about a knight who travels with an elf and is trying to defeat a dark mage

Tags: story-identification, novel

I haven't seen this book for over 5 years and, try as I might, I can't seem to find a single thing about it online.

- Fantasy novel series.
- I THINK that the cover usually had some type of arch in the background of the art work, and it would usually feature the main protagonist who was a knight (I think in some of the art, he'd be wearing loose cloth in a Greek robe-esque style).
- He was travelling with an elf who wore stockings.
- In one book, said elf gets trapped in a parallel dimension "jail"(???) and meets a dwarf, who I'm pretty sure gets killed later on.
- The story kind of centres around this knight and him trying to beat this dark mage or something.
- There was a point in one book where there was an enchanted forest surrounding a castle, and the forest and things inside it would attack whoever entered.
- There was this female character. I can't remember whether she was a princess or not but her name started with a 'C;' it was a unique name, along the lines of 'Crysanthia' or something like that.
- One other thing I think I remember was the knight and elf travelling and finding the knight's hometown, where he had built a home for his wife.

I read these books in about 2016/2017 and they were definitely a fair bit older than that, I say that due to the colour of the pages, condition of the books and the artwork used on the cover. I couldn't accurately estimate when it could have been published though.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you read this and when do you think it might've been published?

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/20774) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: My knowledge is thin, but maybe check out David Eddings? One of his protagonists is named Ce'Nedra

Comment: No time to delve now, but has to be a dragonlance novel. Tower of high sorcery in Palanthalas and the Shoikan Grove,Tanis, Crysania Tarinius. I'd suggest a book set after dragons of spring dawning.

Comment: @Adele-NexusofPotlucks Not Eddings. No elves in his works.

Comment: @AerusDar You are an absolute life saver!!! I was beginning to think these books were a fever dream but you, my saviour! Have solved all my problems today!! Thankyou so much for your help!

Comment: Please don't edit your answer into your question.  If you don't want to wait for AerusDar to post an answer, you could post it yourself, but please post the actual answer.

Comment: @AerusDar you should post that as the answer.

Answer (score 4):

This is a [Dragonlance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dragonlance) story / jumbled memory of stories. My best guess would be a book from [Dragonlance Legends](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dragonlance_Legends).

*Fantasy novel series.*
Tick

*I THINK that the cover usually had some type of arch in the background of the art work, and it would usually feature the main protagonist who was a knight (I think in some of the art, he'd be wearing loose cloth in a Greek robe-esque style).*
This tracks well with typical [Dragonlance Covers](https://goodman-games.com/blog/2022/03/22/classic-covers-dragonlance/)

*He was travelling with an elf who wore stockings.*
Strange recollection, but OK. [stockings were all the rage in Palanthas.](https://dragonlancenexus.com/fashions-of-palanthas/) Actually, this could be the Kender, [Tasslehoff Burrfoot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tasslehoff_Burrfoot).

*In one book, said elf gets trapped in a parallel dimension "jail"(???) and meets a dwarf, who I'm pretty sure gets killed later on.*
This sounds a lot like [Bupu](https://dragonlance.fandom.com/wiki/Bupu_Bulp), a gully dwarf befriended by Raistlin in [Dragons of Autumn Twighlight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dragons_of_Autumn_Twilight), who indeed is killed. However, give I believe your thinking of a Legends story, set well after Bupu, it's possible this is Gnimsh, a gnome killed by Raistlin.

*The story kind of centers around this knight and him trying to beat this dark mage or something.*
Given my Dragonlance Legends suspicion, this would be Caramon Majere.

*There was a point in one book where there was an enchanted forest surrounding a castle, and the forest and things inside it would attack whoever entered.*
[Tower of High Sorcery at Palanthas](https://dragonlance.fandom.com/wiki/Tower_of_High_Sorcery_at_Palanthas), surrounded by the Shoikan Grove, which was enchanted, and could attack those who entered, acting on the will of the master of the tower.

*There was this female character. I can't remember whether she was a princess or not but her name started with a 'C;' it was a unique name, along the lines of 'Crysanthia' or something like that.*
[Crysania Tarinius](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Dragonlance_characters#Crysania) fits the bill nicely.

*One other thing I think I remember was the knight and elf travelling and finding the knight's hometown, where he had built a home for his wife.*
This would be Caramon, the town of Solace, and his wife [Tika Waylan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_major_Dragonlance_characters#Tika_Waylan)